# Extract body of soap response

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, plsql, extract

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
  <si xmlns="http://tempuri.org">LOCALE=,USERID=</si>
 </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:data xmlns:ns2="http://service/">
       <return>
          <id>10010</id>
          <approvementDate>16.06.2011 - 17:02:08</approvementDate>
          <currentYear>2010</currentYear>
          <resultCode>Success</resultCode>
       </return>
    </ns2:data>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to extract the body node of the xml by using plsql ,below code works fine for Header

```
     extract('/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/child::node()','xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"');
```

but I could not get the body by this code

```
     extract('/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/soap:Body/child::node()','xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"');
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body and Header are both direct descendant of the root node. You are trying to get a Body node *under* a Header node.There is no such child node of Header, so you get no result.

The path should be:

```
extract('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/child::node()','xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"');
```

which as part of a PL/SQL block (with made-up table, column and variable names) would get:

```
declare
  l_doc xmltype;
  l_body xmltype;
begin
  select xml_col into l_doc from your_table;
  l_body := l_doc.extract('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/child::node()',
    'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_body.getstringval);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

<ns2:data xmlns:ns2="http://service/">
  <return>
    <id>10010</id>
    <approvementDate>16.06.2011 - 17:02:08</approvementDate>
    <currentYear>2010</currentYear>
    <resultCode>Success</resultCode>
  </return>
</ns2:data>
```

Comment: thank you very much,I've also tried this way but I've been wrong at checking the result from beginning.